# JavaScript, PHP - Sending multiple database records to variables or table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create application based on OpenLayers which will take records with coordinates from MSSQL database using php, and then send it to JavaScript function responsible for initializing markers. I've managed to send single php variable with coordinates from database to JS function, but can't think of a solution that will send all of the records from our table in the database to variables. I've tried creating a while loop in a while loop, but the efforts were futile. Long story short, is there a way to put SELECTED coordinates (longitude and latitude) in some sort of two tables from where we could use the data for javascript initializing markers?

```
$lon = "SELECT longitude FROM pozycje";
$lat = "SELECT latitude FROM pozycje";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $lat);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $LATI = $row['latitude'];
      echo $row['latitude'];
}

echo " ";
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $lon);
if( $stmt2 === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $LONG = $row['longitude'];
      echo $row['longitude'];
}
```

Comment: `is there a way to put SELECTED coordinates (longitude and latitude) in some sort of two tables from where we could use the data for javascript initializing markers?` yes, a lot of different ways

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @Lashane Thanks for suggesting at least one of your useful ways to find the solution buddy, have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after hour of thinking I found  the solution. I hope somebody will find use for it.

```
       <?php 
    $query = "SELECT lonstacja, latstacja FROM pozycja_stacja"; 
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);
    if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $lonstacja = $row["lonstacja"];
        $latstacja = $row["latstacja"];?>
        var lonstacja = '<?php echo $lonstacja ?>';
        var latstacja = '<?php echo $latstacja ?>';
        init_markers(lonstacja, latstacja);
        <?php
    }
    ?>
}
```